# How to bind an optional to bool in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var error: Error?

  func ok() {
    error = nil
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {}.alert("Error", isPresented: error != nil) {
      Button("OK", action: ok)
    } message: {
      Text(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
  }
}
```

How do you resolve `Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'`? When you try to do this SwiftUI errors.

Answer (score 3):

You could listen for changes of the error property and update a bool state value which can be passed as a binding.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var error: Error?
  @State var shouldShowModal = false

  func ok() {
    error = nil
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {}.alert("Error", isPresented: $shouldShowModal) {
      Button("OK", action: ok)
    } message: {
      Text(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
    .onChange(of: error) { newValue in 
      shouldShowModal = newValue != nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad idea to have two states slaved together like having a separate Bool and Error optional. It opens the door to accidentally having the bool be true while the error is nil or the error containing a value while the bool is false. Neither of these are valid in this context.

I think it's better to do away with the Bool. Something like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var error: Error?

    var body: some View {
        VStack { }
            .alert(
                isPresented: Binding(get: { error != nil }, set: { if !$0 { error = nil } }),
                content: {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(error!.localizedDescription), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
            )
    }
}
```